# Book where a girl finds a being in a field and it transforms to look like her

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a few years ago and I can't remember what it was called. I think it was about this girl who lives on a farm and one night finds this "being" in the field. She bathed it, fed it, let it sleep in her home for the night. Then in the morning it had transformed to look almost exactly like her.

They didn't want people to freak out so they said they were cousins and named the being Anne or Annie I think. Later some handsome man visited the farm and the "being" transformed into him. And I don't remember what they changed his name to. Then the girl and the "being" got married and had some kids together.

All I remember from the ending was that one of their daughters was playing on a tractor and fell and sliced herself in half and died.